# Equivalent definition of Lebesgue measurability for sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definition, lebesgue-measure

When introducing measurability, we noted that we wanted the following property to hold for disjoint $A, B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

$m(A \cup B) = m(A)+m(B)$ (additivity)

We then defined a set A to be measurable iff $\forall$ sets $E \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}),$

$m(E) = m(E \cap A)+m(E \cap A^c)$

This begs the question: Are the measurable sets the (unique) maximal collection of sets from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ which are additive? If so, our "goal" is certainly achieved. Of course it is also a question whether such a maximal set is even unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a slight correction: you presumably want additivity for **disjoint** $A, B$. And I assume "$m$" is supposed to be the usual Lebesgue outer measure.

That said: there are collections of sets which satisfy additivity, but contain non-measurable sets; for example, any singleton $\{A\}$ trivially satisfies additivity. We can do better: any two sets $X$ and $Y$ which are *separated* - that is, $X\subseteq A, Y\subseteq B$ for disjoint open $A, B$ - satisfy the additivity requirement. So we can get collections with several nonmeasurable sets, which satisfy additivity.

Finally, since additivity is a *local* requirement, Zorn's lemma tells us that any family satisfying additivity is contained in a maximal such family.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! A perfect answer. I have also added the disjoint requirement which I neglected.